# Making my own custom class why it gave me an error

Tags: java

I had the following error:

> Non-static variable this can not be referenced from a static context

This is the code

```java
cellphone dg = new Cellphone()

public class Oops7 {
    class Cellphone {
        void ring() {
            System.out.println("Your phon is ringing");
        }

        void sing() {
            System.out.println("Your phon is singing");
        }

        void vibrate() {
            System.out.println("Your phon is vibrating");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cellphone dg = new Cellphone();
        dg.vibrate();
        dg.sing();
        dg.ring();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because class `Cellphone` is an [inner class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html). To make this work, make it a `static` nested class: `static class Cellphone`.

Answer (score 0):

```
cellphone dg = new Cellphone()

public class Oops7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cellphone dg = new Cellphone();
        dg.vibrate();
        dg.sing();
        dg.ring();
    }

    static class Cellphone {
        void ring() {
            System.out.println("Your phon is ringing");
        }

        void sing() {
            System.out.println("Your phon is singing");
        }

        void vibrate() {
            System.out.println("Your phon is vibrating");
        }
    }
}
```

You should put you **main** method at the beginning of your class, it is easier to read for other people. The correction to your problem is what the comment is, you have to add *static* to your class.